# Downloaded .csv file contains HTML tags as text

Tags: php, csv, html

I want to **download** a **.csv** file through link.For that a Download link is defined in a template file.

To generate .csv file I have written a piece of code as follows.

```
public function loadPartnerApplicantData() {
    $inboundBo = BoFactory::getInboundHttpRequestBo();
    $fileType = $inboundBo->getSanitizedGetParam('f');
    $formId = $inboundBo->getSanitizedGetParam('fid');
    ServiceFactory::getFormService()->loadFormDetails($formId);
    $dbTable = BoFactory::getFormBo()->getFormDbTable($formId);
    $formName = slugify(BoFactory::getFormBo()->getFormName());
    $fileName = $formName . "." . time();
    $fieldMasterSqlQuery = "SELECT field_name,field_label FROM" . FORM_FIELDS_MASTER_v2 . "where form_id='$formId' order by serial_no";
    $fieldMasterSqlQueryStatus = mysql_query(mysql_fetch_assoc($fieldMasterSqlQuery));
    $csvHeader = "";
    $fieldNameArray = array();
    foreach ($fieldMasterSqlQueryStatus as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['field_name'] == 'declaration' || $value['field_name'] == 'docPicture') {
            continue;
        }
        $csvHeader.= "\"{$value['field_label']}\";";
        $fieldNameArray[] = $value['field_name'];
    }
    $queryString = implode(",", $fieldNameArray);
    $dbTableSqlQuery = "SELECT $queryString FROM `$dbTable`";
    $dbTableSqlQueryStaus = mysql_query(mysql_fetch_assoc($dbTableSqlQuery));
    ef_clearBuffer();
   // To generate csv
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    echo($csvHeader);
    foreach ($dbTableSqlQueryStaus as $applicantData) {
        echo "\n";
        foreach ($fieldNameArray as $fieldName) {
            echo "\"$applicantData[$fieldName]\";";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

And the required .csv is generated .

**But at the end of .csv file HTML tags of the browser is getting displayed.** which should not be there.

Please suggest me **to remove the html content** from the generated .csv file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't try to remove those characters, that is curing the symptom, not the cause. Find out where those characters come from instead and fix that issue. Start by writing that content into a file instead of delivering it to the browser. You can do that elegant by means of output boffering so that you don't have to change the code above. Then check if the files content already contains the html characters. I suspect not, in that case you have a problem with a proxy or cache trying to be 'intelligent'. Check the delivered headers in that case.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha for your suggestion. I got my work done by adding **exit;** statement to the code at the end of the function (after the csv is prepared.)

Comment: And you call that a solution? So what is the answer? Where do the html sequences come from? What makes you sure something similar does not happen tomorrow again? The most important thing when you want to get better in programming is _to understand_ what is going on. That is different from trying 'round 'til things appear to work, somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your function handles the request till the end (i.e., delivers all data), and you don't want the framework (whichever you're using) to continue processing, add

```
exit(0);
```

as last line of your function. That will halt the processing after the content is delivered and prevent the framework/environment from sending additional data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already had some echo commands before the header manipulation, then the .csv file which you want to download will contains all strings you have written before.